# For ax % b = c, where a, b, and c are known, how do I find a compliant x?

Tags: math, modulo

From what I can tell, this is *not* the multiplicative inverse of modulo (which is what I keep finding with google searches), since x is the unknown.  b and a are relatively prime, and % is the modulus operator used in most programming languages.  Using a for loop to find matches could take up to 4 billion iterations to find the matching value of x.  I know there is more than one value for x which solves this equation... I need the smallest that is greater than 0.

I know this could be re-written as ax - by = c where both x and y are unknown, but I don't know how to solve this equation for a matching x where both x and y are integers.  I keep running into Euclid's solution for gcd(m, n) = 1 in conjunction to this problem, but although I can implement this algorithm, I don't know how to use the results to solve my problem.

Although this appears to be a math question, it is in the domain of "computer" math and algorithms instead of the theoretical I keep finding with google searches.  I'm hoping for a simple algorithm, equation, or built-in math call if possible - sample code would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: A better site for this is http://math.stackexchange.com/ or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com  have voted to move there.

Comment: @Darren how do you vote to move to math.stackexchange? It doesn't appear in my list of sites to migrate to.

Comment: if a and b are not relatively prime there might not be a solution

Comment: Have a look at [the Wikipedia article on the Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm#Linear_Diophantine_equations).  You'll find your exact problem there -- even with the same variable names!  Also have a look at the article ["Extended Euclidean algorithm"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer, I just add free text.